# How can I run Old version Ionic project on browser and can also run on device after built apk?

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run my old ionic project which has version `3.9` but it's not running on browser showing and giving runtime error like

> webpack and cordova are undefined

I had make changes in environment like switched my ionic version to `3.9` and still its not working please let me help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Add the code or errors message?

Comment: most propably you will have to switch to a older node version , try using nvm and downgrade nodejs as necessary also do the same to  global  verion of ionic   and angular . after all the above step run `npm install` also make sure you have installed correct version of cordova

Comment: remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` . also try to run `npm rebuild node-sass`